# the setValue() not storing the correct value in the combox field-EXTJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

i'm want to set a value dynamically,

```
 $cls.superclass.constructor.call(this, Ext.apply({

              autoHeight: true,
              items: [
                this.combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
                  width: 75,
                  emptyText: $L('Select...'),
                  mode: 'local',
                  displayField : 'title',
                  valueField: 'key',
                  triggerAction: 'all',
                  store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                       fields: ['key', 'title'],
                       data: [
                         ["titletest","Title"],
                         ["nametest","Name"]]
                   }),
                   listeners: {
 'select': function(){
  this.show();
},
scope: this
}
                })]



    },cfg));
```

I do:

```
show: function(fld) {
  this.combo.setValue(fld.value);
}
```

the fld.value sets the value as "nametest" or "titletest" rather than "Title" or "Name"

How to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: what value do you get if you were to adjust your select callback as so 
```
select: function(fld) {
            console.log("selected",fld.value);
}
```
if you get back "Title" or "Name" then the value is correct but is displaying what you have set as the `displayField`. Is that what you want?

Comment: so my `displayField` is set as `title` and you can see from the `fields:` I ahve `key` and `title` and I want to display title as my value. I get the `fld.value` as `titletest` when I `console.log(fld.value)`

Comment: so you want to display the displayField as selected? so essentially when you select "Title" the selection will display "Title" but the value will be "titletest" ?

Comment: yes, that is right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the data definition should be like this using the keys as in fields as defined'

```
fields: ['key', 'title'],
    data : [
            {"key":"titletest", "title":"Title"},
            {"key":"nametest", "title":"Name"}
    ]
```